# How to pass Username and password of Named Credentials in HTTP Get

Tags: integration, callout, httprequest, namedcredentials

I am trying to send an send a request using get method of HTTP Request and I need to pass the username and password of Named credentials in the URL as username as clientID and password as the client secret

Below is the code

```
@future (callout=true)
    webservice static void requestCall(String first, String second, String third) {

        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        Http http = new Http();
       String url ='?first=' + first+ '&second=' + second+'&third=' + third+'&client_id=' + '{!HTMLENCODE($Credential.Username)}' + '&client_secret=' + '{!HTMLENCODE($Credential.Password)}';

        req.setEndpoint('callout:Named_Credentials'+url);
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setCompressed(true);
        req.setTimeout(120000);
        try {
            res = http.send(req);
            System.debug(req);
        } catch(System.CalloutException e) {
            System.debug('Callout error: '+ e);
            System.debug(res.toString());
        }
}
```

I am getting a response following response in the debug

```
{
  "message": "Bad Request"
}
```

Also, when I store the client Id and client secret in custom setting and use them, it is working fine and getting a proper response.

Any suggestions or help that how can I fetch the username and password from Named credentials

Comment: @kurunve I am using GET method, it's not working for when setting method as GET

Comment: If you need the client id and client secret, I presume this is an OAuth connection? You should use the OAuth authentication mode of Named Credentials to handle the connection for you.

Comment: @sfdcfox No, I just need to fetch the username and password from the Named credentials as Password Authentication in the Apex to add them in the URL string as client Id and client secret, I have also tried using  {!($Credential.Username)} and {!($Credential.Password)} but it is not working when I am using GET as method

Comment: You can't... it's not supported. The best you can do is post it as a URL-encoded body.

Comment: @sfdcfox When I am using a Post method then I am getting method not supported in the response,

Comment: @sfdcfox , I just need to get the Username and password which are stored in the Named credentials to pass in the URL string using the GET method